# Как правильнее (литературнее)?

Tags: грамотная-речь

"Распечатал документ на принтере", или "напечатал документ на принтере"?

Comment: Как вижу, форумчане к единому мнению не пришли. Вопрос, собственно, потому и задал, что на мой взгляд, слово "распечатать"  (как и "распечатка") напоминает слегка колхозный сленг.

Comment: Если и сленг, то никак не колхозный, а компьютерный. Как это Вы печатать на принтере будете? На нём не печатают, а распечатывают уже готовый текст, печатают на пишущей машинке. Когда речь идёт о наборе текста на компьютере, говорить "печатать на..." по-моему, некорректно, печатаем мы с помощью клавиатуры в программе "Ворд", например, а  "напечатать на принтере" означает "размножить", но ведь Вы имели в виду не "размножить", а именно набрать текст?

Answer (score 1):

Разная сочетаемость.

**Распечатал** на принтере, но **напечатал** на пишущей машинке. Дело, в частности, в том, что в случае принтера речь идёт о печати *уже набранного* текста, и акцентируется однократное *завершающее* действие, требующее от оператора "кнопку нажать". В издательском деле тоже употребляются разные слова для всего процесса (напечатать в газете, книгу) и завершающей его части (отпечатать тираж, имея законченный набор). Подобное различие есть и в английском: to print (просто напечатать) и to print out (распечатать).

Answer (score 0):

Глагол "распечатать" произошел от разговорного существительного "распечатка" (а не наоборот), а "распечатка" появилась вместе с широким распространением печатающих устройств. Так что "распечатать", имхо, тоже имеет налет разговорности.

Comment: *Глагол "распечатать" произошел от разговорного существительного "распечатка"* — Очень сомнительно.

Comment: Очень похоже. Ибо на наших глазах все и произошло.

Comment: Совсем не похоже. Похоже на первую пришедшую в голову ассоциацию (которые далеко не всегда приходят в голову по законам этимологии). Я и не спорил бы, если бы не на наших глазах.

Answer (score 0):

Оба варианта соответствуют литературной норме. Это зафиксировано современными словарями.

**РАСПЕЧАТАТЬ**, -аю, -аешь; св. что.
...
2. Напечатать на бумаге (с плёнки, ленты и т.п.); размножить с помощью печатного устройства. *Р. фотографии. Р. компьютерную версию текста.*

**НАПЕЧАТАТЬ**, -аю, -аешь; св. (нсв. печатать). что.
1. Воспроизвести текст, рисунок и т.п. с помощью каких-л. устройств. *Н. на пишущей машинке, принтере. Н. крупным шрифтом. Н. внизу страницы. Н. в типографии. Книга напечатана на прекрасной бумаге.*

Answer (score 0):

В словаре Ушакова слово *распечатать* связано только со вскрытием письма или пакета, взломом печати (той, которой послание запечатано). У Ожегова *распечатать* значит напечатать *во многих экземплярах*.
А распечатывание в одном экземпляре на принтере — это был сначала программистский жаргон, потом он начал входить в словари. Сейчас оба варианта соответствуют литературной норме (@grizzly), и это касается использования принтеров тоже. Однако *распечатать*, по-моему, имеет налет разговорности (@Niemand). Вряд ли его употребляют в сугубо официальных документах. А слова *напечатать* и *отпечатать* в своем старом добром значении не потеряли своей актуальности и в наше время. Как источник для печати, текст, набранный в старинной типографии, ничем не отличается от набранного на современном компьютере. Можно согласиться с @Alex_ander, что *отпечатать* документ звучит лучше, чем *напечатать*. По-моему, есть еще один нюанс. Если виртуальная форма — лишь промежуточная стадия, то документ надо *отпечатать*, а если его предназначение — жить в виртуальном мире, а мы решили вдруг "вытащить" его оттуда, превратив в бумажный вариант, тогда *распечатать*.

Comment: Ну вот, еще один ответ добавил туманности. Насчет "нюанса"... Привожу полностью предложение (оно должно звучать литературно).  На этот раз предусмотрительно забронировал жилье через специальный сайт интернета и распечатал подтверждающий документ на принтере.

Comment: В данном случае я бы употребил слово "распечатал". Два агрумента в его пользу: (1) ситуция бытовая, стиль близкий к разговорному, (2) подтверждающий документ мог бы оставаться и в виртуальной форме, но вы его перевели в печатную; по-моему, здесь больше подходит слово "распечатать" (см. "нюанс").